# Why can't I get query params in ```getStaticProps```?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I will make it simple:

Link: `http://localhost:3000/product/bioCloths?activeCategory=medium&id=0`

File path: `pages/product/[product].js`.

Expected:  `product: "bioCloths, activeCategory: "medium", id: "0"`

using `getStaticProps` at `[product].js`:

```
const ProductDetails = (props) => {
  console.log("initial props", props);

  return <div>product details...</div>
};

export default ProductDetails;

export async function getStaticProps(context) {

  return {
    props: {
     context: context
    },
  };
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  return {
    paths: [{ params: { product: "1" } }, { params: { product: "2" } }],
    fallback: true,
  };
}
```

`Props` returns: `context: params: product: "bioCloths"`, excluding the query params.

Now if I use the deprecated `getInitialProps` instead:

```
ProductDetails.getInitialProps = (context) => {
  const activeCategory = context.query.activeCategory;
  const id = context.query.id;
  const product = context.query.product;

  return {
    activeCategory: activeCategory,
    id: id,
    product: product,
  };
};
```

props logs `activeCategory: "medium" id: "0" product: "bioCloths"`

I need to get these all of these props so I can `fetch` data before the client mounts.

I understand that `getInitialProps` is now deprecated, but it works. Why is not `getStaticProps` working, and should I use it instead of `serverSideProps`?

This is an ecommerce, and there is no way I can set `getStaticPaths` for hundreds of possibilities, to work along with `getStaticProps` so I guess that in this case I should use `getInitialProps or getServerSideProps`?

P.S - `getServerSideProps` hits me an error stating that it will only accept `.json` files.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to one of the maintainers of `Nextjs` this is the reply for anyone learning this framework:

> `getStaticProps` generates the page at build time. There's no possible way to know the custom query params your visitors can use at build time.

> `getInitialProps` and `getServerSideProps` can know all the possible query params because the page is generated at runtime, whenever you receive a new request.

You can learn more about the above [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#two-forms-of-pre-rendering).

"

This discussion can be read on [Github](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/17529#discussioncomment-88655)

Answer (score 7):

If your page uses a dynamic route, `params` contain the route parameters. For instance, If the page name is `[id].js`, then `params` will look as follows:

```
{ id: /* something */ }
```

You can get **URL params** from inside your `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps` function with the context argument.
Here’s an example with `getStaticProps`:

```
// pages/[id].js

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
    const { params } = context;
    const id = params.id;

    const data = /* Fetching data with the id */

    return {
        props: data,
    }
}
```

You can do the same with `getServerSideProps`:

```
// pages/[id].js

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const { params } = context;
  const id = params.id;

  /* ... */
}
```